# Is admin.py necessary is every django app?

Tags: django

I have created a simple django app with the help of tutorial found in djangoproject.com . There was no admin.py file created. Do I need to create one for the functioning of the app?

Answer (score 3):

`admin.py` if it exists, will be imported by `admin.autodiscover()`. It is for the [optional admin app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) and is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You only need to create admin.py in order to access the object/module in the admin-view or/and override the default save-functions.